# Upload File Dropbox use VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

```
    Dim _client = New DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    Dim arq As String = "d:\teste.txt"
    Dim filebytes = New FileInfo(arq)
    Dim content As Byte() = _client.GetFileContentFromFS(filebytes)
    Dim result = _client.UploadFile("/", arq, content) '<<<<erro: "use the "new" keyword to create an objtect instance
    MsgBox(result.ToString())
```

erro: "use the "new" keyword to create an objtect instance!!!

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried: Dim _client As DropNetClient and then below it _client = New DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") ?

Comment: Also set a breakpoint and step through to make sure your variables are indeed something and they are what they're supposed to be.

Comment: Also your missing your login for the client...